# cant seem to get enable-migrations working Successfully installed but not added

Tags: asp.net

I am nw to Entity Framework and ASP.NEt in general..i have instaled EF and when i write  enable-migrations i get following line No context type was found in the assembly 'Demogorgon'.

I have tried to 
1. instal and uninstal EF
2. Made sure that i have selected the right project as default (easy there is only one in the dropdown)
3. used for instalation of EF Console or Manage nugets
4. i am ofc reading answers here and elsewhere but since i am quite new to this i am not how to proceed

```
   Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'EntityFramework.6.4.4' with respect to project 'Demogorgon', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2'
    Gathering dependency information took 1.14 sec
    Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'EntityFramework.6.4.4' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
    Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
    Resolving actions to install package 'EntityFramework.6.4.4'
    Resolved actions to install package 'EntityFramework.6.4.4'
    Retrieving package 'EntityFramework 6.4.4' from 'nuget.org'.
    Adding package 'EntityFramework.6.4.4' to folder 'C:\Users\novot\source\repos\Demogorgon\packages'
    Added package 'EntityFramework.6.4.4' to folder 'C:\Users\novot\source\repos\Demogorgon\packages'
    Added package 'EntityFramework.6.4.4' to 'packages.config'
    **Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 6.4.4' to Demogorgon**
    Executing nuget actions took 1.49 sec
    Time Elapsed: 00:00:02.7731151
    PM> Enable-Migrations
    No context type was found in the assembly 'Demogorgon'.
    PM> enable-migrations
    No context type was found in the assembly 'Demogorgon'.
    PM>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in Package Manager Console(Default project drop-down option) you have selected the correct project(the project where your DBContext class is), and try again

Comment: I have already mentioned in the question that i have done that

Comment: Enable-Migrations -ProjectName <YOUR_PROJECT_NAME> -ContextTypeName <YOUR_CONTEXT_NAME> -> could be an alternative ; Don't forget to use the full path to your context name as well